# Ruby on Rails: Add subfolder in app directory with files specific to models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, loading, subdirectory

I am writing a gem which will handle all kind of notifications for a model (sms, mobile and browser notifications)

in rails project under app directory created new folder 'notifiers' which contain files like

```
app/notifiers/user_notifier.rb

class UserNotifier < ApplicationNotifier
  def send_reminder
   {
     type: 'sms',
     content: 'hi everyone',
     recipients: [12134343,2342322,3434343]
   }
  end
end
```

this user_notifier file should be against User model. means that this method send_reminder should be available to instance/object of User

`User.last.send_reminder`
So, issue is

- how to make files of notifiers folder to model specific (user.rb model file has user_notifier.rb file in notifiers folder)
- how this file user_notifier.rb methods would be available to user model

This is possible with concerns and namespaces but this would create messy code

Comment: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/advanced/modules.html and https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html. You don't actually have to do anything - just include the file.

Comment: Hi @max please have a look I already requested in question that with concerns and namespaces(including in model) it's possible. But i wanna do this just like rails behave for it's own MVC pattern. For a model one don't need to write any configuration that which is corresponding controller  of this model. thanks

Comment: You can check if `UserNotifier` is loaded with the command `rails runner "UserNotifier.new"`. If you get an error can you send me the result of `rails runner "puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths"` and tell me which version of Rails you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Léonard, he posted the solution but while writing the gem we need to handle these configuration from gem. Because when someone use our gem he/she don't have to write any configuration related logic in application_record.rb manually.

posting it just to ensure that in future may it helpful for someone else.

what i did to tackle this issue (to attach gem with a model we add act_as_notifier in model with which we want it to be configured)

- In model_config.rb class of notifier gem
- Have @model_class & find corresponding notifier class
- Add attr_accessor in notifier class and initialize it with model object
- Also define custom getter and setters notifier attribute

```
#rails_notifier/model_config.rb
    def initialize(model_class)
      @model_class = model_class
      
      # get model corresponding notifier class
      # for User model class, there would UserNotifier class
      # under notifiers folder of app directory
      # getting notitifer class name
      notifier_class = "#{@model_class.name}Notifier"
      
      # Notifier class attribute set later set with model object
      attribute_name = @model_class.name.underscore
      
      # register a `notifier` method in model class
      # 'method_name' is a method of notifier class
      # and options hash contain sender
      @model_class.class_eval do
        define_method(:notifier) do |method_name, options|
          # create notifier class object
          notifier_ = notifier_class.constantize.new

          # define setter for notifier attribute
          notifier_.send(:define_singleton_method, "#{attribute_name}=".to_sym) do |value|
            instance_variable_set("@" + attribute_name.to_s, value)
          end

          # define getter for notifier attribute
          notifier_.send(:define_singleton_method, attribute_name.to_sym) do
            instance_variable_get("@" + attribute_name.to_s)
          end

          # self point to the object of model
          # e.g User.last.notifier(:send_reminder), slef = User.last
          # set notifier attribute with model object
          notifier_.send("#{attribute_name}=".to_sym, self)
          notifier_hash = notifier_.send(method_name)
          RailsNotifier.notify(notifier_hash) if notifier_hash.present?
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: If you consider that including the code inside a gem in a « gem way » is needed in the answer, can you update you question to clearly add it to the requirements? Besides, you should consider using concerns instead of metaprogramming. The rails way to include code in existing classes is concerns. If you check the code of the gems inside rails (active_record, active_support, etc), concerns are favored over metaprogramming when possible because: the code is clearer and metaprogramming comes with a quite negative performance impact

Comment: @LéonardHenriquez i voted you answer it's good(unfortunately forget to mark it as accepted done now). but i just update answer to show that how we can move it directly to gem.

i don't want to do it via concerns and namespaces. we are separating messy code from existing application. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**How to make files of notifiers folder to model specific?**

All the code under app folder is loaded without any config.
You just need to respect the naming convention for the class.
In this case `UserNotifier` is the right name for `app/notifiers/user_notifier.rb`.

**How this file user_notifier.rb methods would be available to user model?**

```
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your code

  def send_notification(notification_name, recipients)
    notifier = "#{self.class.name}Notifier".constantize.new()
    send(notification_name, recipients)
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # your code

  # a method where you want to send a notification
  def foo
    send_notification(:reminder, [id])
  end
end

# app/notifiers/user_notifier.rb
class UserNotifier < ApplicationNotifier
  def reminder(recipients)
   {
     type: 'sms',
     content: 'hi everyone',
     recipients: recipients
   }
  end
end
```